# PayPal API - NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)

Tags: php, json, paypal

i have the following problem. I try to create a plan with the PayPal API with this code:

```
$clientId = "xxx";
$secret = "xxx";
$mode = ".sandbox";
$product_id = "xxx";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api".$mode.".paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $clientId.":".$secret);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($result);
$access_token=$json->access_token;
curl_close($ch);

$ch = curl_init();
$headers=array('Content-Type:application/json','Authorization:Bearer '.$access_token); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api".$mode.".paypal.com/v1/billing/plans");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{
"product_id": "'.$product_id.'",
  "name": "Basic",
  "description": "Basic",
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "billing_cycles": [
    {
      "frequency": {
        "interval_unit": "MONTH",
        "interval_count": 1
      },
      "tenure_type": "REGULAR",
      "sequence": 2,
      "total_cycles": 0,
      "pricing_scheme": {
        "fixed_price": {
          "value": "'.$amount.'",
          "currency_code": "EUR"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "payment_preferences": {
    "auto_bill_outstanding": true,
        "setup_fee": {
          "currency_code": "EUR",
          "value": "0"
        },
        "setup_fee_failure_action": "CONTINUE",
        "payment_failure_threshold": 3
      },
  "taxes": {
    "percentage": "19",
    "inclusive": true
  }
}');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo 'Curl-Fehler: ' . curl_error($ch);
$json = json_decode($result);
$plan_id=$json->id;
curl_close($ch);
echo $plan_id;
```

But i get the following error-message:

NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)

Before i created the product with the following code and it works fine:

```
$clientId = "xxx";
$secret = "xxx";
$mode = ".sandbox";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api".$mode.".paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $clientId.":".$secret);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($result);
$access_token=$json->access_token;
curl_close($ch);

$ch = curl_init();
$headers=array('Content-Type:application/json','Authorization:Bearer '.$access_token); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api".$mode.".paypal.com/v1/catalogs/products");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{
"name": "xxx",
  "description": "xxx",
  "type": "SERVICE",
  "category": "SOFTWARE",
  "home_url": "https://domain.de/"
}');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($result);
$product_id=$json->id;
curl_close($ch);
echo $product_id;
```

so i don´t know, what i´m doing wrong in the first code, when the second code is working. Can someone help me?

thank you very much